# Series with double Sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The problem is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx \left(\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{\sin^2(k\theta)}{1+x^2+\cos^2k\theta}\right)  $$

Is that "$\prod$" the same as "$\sum$"?

I don't know how to start.

What I tried doing was focusing on the $\prod$ equation. Which I concluded is convergent by comparing $$\dfrac{\sin^2(k\theta)}{1+x^2}$$ ,as my $b_n$, to the original which $a_n<b_n$. Since $\sin^2(k\theta)$ is alternating, I just used the Alternating series test in which the limit of $b_n$ is $0$.

But the $\sum$ part goes to infinity...

I have no idea what to do next or if I am even doing it right.

Comment: As the MathJax code, i.e. \prod, should suggest, $\displaystyle \text{“}\ \prod_{k=1}^n a_k\  \text{''}$ means $a_1 a_2 a_3\cdots a_n$, a product, not a sum. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

The first is a "sum"; the second one is a "product".

Indeed, for example, we have:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n k =  \frac{1}{2}n \cdot (1+n)$$

whilst

$$\prod_{k = 1}^{n} k = n!$$

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification. How would I say it terms of words? So that I can search for more examples.

Comment: And how would I start the problem? I searched up that multiplying log can turn the product to a sum. Would that work?

Comment: The first operation is called "sum" or "series". Try to search for "series of functions" or "convergences of series". 
The second one is a product, try to search something like "infinite products". Generally you might find those topics in books of calculus.

For the log function you have a special case, because:
_
$$\log\left(\prod_{k = 1}^n a_k\right) = \log(a_1\cdot a_2\cdot ... a_n) = \log(a_1) + \cdots \log(a_n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \log(a_k)$$

But for your example it's different